# A Bursting Ball of Fun!

Tags: riddle, rhyme, science

> Some say I'm real, some say I'm not,
>   but all would agree that I'm very hot.
>   I jump around from place to place,
>   Lighting up whatever I touch.
>   If you confront me face to face,
>   You won't be left with much.
>   With a shock, I'll leave you astounded,
>   Your friends who see me will be confounded.

What am I?
I'll upload a hint if needed, but I'd like to see if anyone can tackle this first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are

> [ball lightning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_lightning).

Fairly self-explanatory by reading the article, but explained briefly nevertheless:

> A Bursting Ball of Fun!

> You are an exploding ball.

> Some say I'm real, some say I'm not,

> Many have reported you, but scientists have been skeptical.

> but all would agree that I'm very hot.
>   I jump around from place to place,
>   Lighting up whatever I touch.

> You are hot, move around wildly, and are very bright.

> If you confront me face to face,
>   You won't be left with much.

> You have killed people.

> With a shock, I'll leave you astounded,

> You are electric.

> Your friends who see me will be confounded.

> You are a mysterious phenomenon.

Comment: Whoa I read the description at it look amazing ^-^  +1

Comment: Great Job! That was answered way faster than I had anticipated.